# Storing session keys in Android

Tags: android, security, session

How should I handle session keys in my android application?

The client will receive a key and serial number from the server once they've logged in, the serial number will be changed every time the client makes a new request. The key will remain the same until it expires or is destroyed.
These will need to be sent in every https request.

Here's an example of what the key and serial number looks like

```
key: af9bce267343ad72bd6abe7aff58edf2
S/N: 503:960:819
```

Should I use a SQLIte database even though there will be an absolute maximum of 1 session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQLite database would be using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. I would store  the information in the app's `SharedPreferences`:

```
String myKey = "af9bce267343ad72bd6abe7aff58edf2";
String mySerial = "503:960:819";

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

// Set/Store data
edit.putString("session_key", myKey);
edit.putString("serial", mySerial);

// Commit the changes
edit.commit();
```

Whenever you want to retrieve the values again, use:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myKey = pref.getString("session_key", null);
String mySerial = pref.getString("serial", null);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer please.

Comment: @Adam, as Nisalon mentioned, SharedPreferences is a good option, here you can find more documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Consider using edit.apply() instead; commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SharedPreferences`, save the value like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("token", mToken);
            editor.commit();
```

and retrieve it like this

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String token = sharedpreferences.getString("token", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it  in mysqlite database or shared preference